# Need to subtract only the non-zero values in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having dataframe `df`. I need to subtract only non-zero values in dataframe and if its 0 then keep its as 0.

```
  difference = df[value] - 10
```

Help me in doing conditional subtracting efficiently as possible, subtract only if value greater than zero in dataframe.

Dataframe `df`

```
    value
1   0
2   0
3   0 
4   0
5   51.134
6   52.4833
7   53.7698
8   5
```

Expected output:

```
   0
   0
   0 
   0
   41.134
   42.4833
   43.7698
   -5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reaplce` then `fillna`

```
df.replace({0:np.nan}).add(-10).fillna(0)
Out[1638]: 
     value
1   0.0000
2   0.0000
3   0.0000
4   0.0000
5  41.1340
6  42.4833
7  43.7698
8  -5.0000
```

Comment: @ArvinthKumar Yw~ ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I'd just use `where`:

```
In [12]: df.value.where(df.value == 0, df.value - 10)
Out[12]: 
1     0.0000
2     0.0000
3     0.0000
4     0.0000
5    41.1340
6    42.4833
7    43.7698
8    -5.0000
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

This is read as "use the existing `df.value` *where* `df.value == 0`, otherwise use `df.value - 10`".

Comment: Or maybe np.where do the same:-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work!

```
difference = [0 if i == 0 else i-10 for i in df]
```